Drawing points with defined coordinate in \addplot command
I don't understand why latex complains when a try to define named coordinate:
\coordinate (B) at (0.5, 0.405); % Define coordinate B

If I try to put the numbers into \addplot command, everything works well.
So, I don't understand why it behaves like this.
MNWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    title={Scatter Plot},
    legend pos=north west,
]
\coordinate (B) at (0.5, 0.405); % Define coordinate B
\addplot[only marks, mark=*] coordinates {
    (0, 1) % Your data point here
    (B)    % Include coordinate B
};
\legend{Data}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The axis environment makes two passes over the data.  The first determins the max and min coordinates, which are used to compute the axis cs: coordinate system.  This means that (B) is not defined until the second pass, and will not (cannot) be used to determine the range of values.

@cfr: typo corrected.

I understand your problem to mean that you want to define general coordinates and then have them appear in a \addplot.
As already mentioned in the comments, this is difficult or even impossible with the usual TikZ coordinate definition "\coordinate (B) at (0.5, 0.405);".
But you can make it much easier in pgfplots: 
Simply define your coordinates as a table:
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
x,    y
0.5, 0.405
1,    2
...
}\mydata

and then call them up as a tableplot:
\addplot [...] table[x=x,y=y] {\mydata};

MWE:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
x,    y
0.5, 0.405
1,    2
0,    0.5
0.6,  1.5
}\mydata

\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    title={Scatter Plot},
    legend pos=north west,
]
%\coordinate (B) at (0.5, 0.405); % Define coordinate B - will not work in addplot
\addplot[only marks, mark=*] coordinates { (0, 1) };

\addplot [color=red, solid,mark=*, only marks] table[x=x,y=y] {\mydata};

\legend{Data (classic), Data (from table)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I see your point. It partially fits to my problem. I am using the \coordinate command because i also try to use \draw commnad to add tagent in certain point in graph. It surprised me a lot, it's almost unintuitive why the two commands don't work together.

You schould at least within the axes environment write: \coordinate (B) at (axis cs: 0.5, 0.405); This way your data coordinates are scaled to the canvas as needed ... unless you want to access its points in units of cm.
